# Whats a technique that I am not aware of to pull an AC cable through a conduit that is just a little to small

Tags: ac, wiring

I have a lamp I am trying to rewire with one of those bendy necks

I can get the cable inserted 75% of the way through the conduit but then the cable and me don't have enough strength to keep pushing it through. Tried inserting a stiff rod to make sure it's completely straight.

Adding tape/heatshrink tubing to connect it to another wire makes it too wide to insert - even if you pull the wire apart and only attach to one side (to try to pull that through after getting the first wire through).

I could strip the wire back and twist it together with one that goes through but how far would I have to strip back to get decent strength? 1 inch doesn't cut it even with some tape

Or is there some better way to attach something to a wire without increasing its diameter?

I feel like I could compress the cable or try to shave some insulation off but that would be a fire hazard so am not going to try that.

Comment: If cost is no object, you could use teflon insulated wire.  You can often find it on ebay.  Even with the high cost per foot, a short piece would not be that expensive in an absolute sense.

Comment: Generally with clean wire and a good tape job, you should be able to work with 45mm of doubled up wire, so 90mm total length, even for difficult pulls.  Less if you tape the wire securely and both pull and feed the wire at the same time (or affix the wire, pick up the object and walk with it.

Comment: Or simply see if a vacuum cleaner nozzle can be used to constructively pull a suitable string through the conduit. Might work. Simple to try. If it works, the string is then tied to the wire and you carefully pull the wire through.

Comment: what is ID and cable OD, show photo

Comment: Do you know about pulling lube? This question might get better answers on [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Silicone lubricant acts like Vaseline.

Answer (score 4):

Don't push the wire, pull it.

I assume that you can at least get a small, but reasonably strong string through the gooseneck.

Strip the wire, double it back on itself and twist it to make a small loop. Use a nail as a form to keep the loop open, and also get a good, tight twist.

```
________          _
________SSSSSSSS((_)) <---- tie string here
```

Tie the string through the loop. Then you can flatten the loop so it'll fit through the gooseneck.

Use the string to pull the wire through the gooseneck.

Cut off the twisted part and make your connections.

---

Alternative approach:

- Push a single wire through the gooseneck.
- Solder the single wire to both wires of the cable.
- Pull the cable through the gooseneck.
- Cut off the soldered joint and make your connections.